# Do comments in Delphi slow down execution time?

Tags: delphi, comments

quick question: will Delphi 2007 execution time be impacted if I remove comments in `//` or `(* *)` from my code? The end result is an EXE file with possibly thousand lines of comments.

Comment: Delphi is compiled language, not interpreted. Comments have absolutely no impact at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments are simply ignored by the compiler and have no impact on the content of the executable produced when compiling.